# Как разместить вторую кнопку слева от центральной?

Tags: html, css, button

Не выходит расположить кнопки. Необходимо поставить кнопку "скопировать" по центу и слева от нее кнопку "назад". Сейчас обе по центру.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}


.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 9px
}
.btn--primary {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #6c7ff2;
}
.btn--primary:active {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.btn--inside {
  margin-left: -96px;
}

.box div { 
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block; 

}

.box--left{
  float: left;
}

.box--right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box--left">       
          <form action="/back_main" method="POST">
            <button class="btn uppercase btn--back" type="submit">Назад</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="bot-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary uppercase js-textareacopybtn">Скопировать</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо чуть чуть разметку изменить - например вот так

> смотреть на весь экран

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 9px
}

.btn--primary {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}

.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #6c7ff2;
}

.btn--primary:active {
  background: #7f8ff4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn--inside {
  margin-left: -96px;
}

.box div {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box--left">
      <form action="/back_main" method="POST">
        <button class="btn uppercase btn--back" type="submit">Назад</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bot-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary uppercase js-textareacopybtn">Скопировать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```